# Scraping Yelp Reviews With wget

Tags: web-crawler, wget, yelp

I am trying to pull the full html of yelp reviews. I know I can use the API to pull reviews, but I'm collecting a corpus of raw html. I tried the code below, but it gets way more than the reviews. How can I restrict it to jus pages of reviews? It currently scrapes from domains like communityblog.yelp.com, seatme.yelp.com, etc.

```
wget -rH -Dyelp.com http://www.yelp.com/nyc -l 5 -w 2
```

Comment: This works pretty well already. But what would you recommend?

Comment: I just looked up HTML parsers. It's not at all what I'm looking for. I'm looking for all of the raw html

Comment: So you don't want to extract the relevant HTML from all the rest? Can you clarify what you mean by "it gets way more than the reviews"?

Comment: Right I want the whole page. I added some clarifying text. It's scraping yelp blogs, etc.